# Data is not passed on to id page

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to pass data of items to a details page. The navigation works fine. But if I want to use string interpolation to output the chosen item, there is just nothing (an empty output). I tried playing around with the app-routing.module, but that didn't work.

Here is my code.

item.html

```
 <ion-title> {{ item.username }} </ion-title>
```

item.ts

```
loadedItems: Item[];
  item: Item;
...
    openRankdet() {
        this.router.navigate(['itemdetail/:id'])
      }
```

item.model.ts

```
export class Item {
    constructor(
        public id: string, 
        public username: string, 
        public imageUrl: string,
        public imageUrl2: string,
         ) {

         }
}
```

item.service

```
 private _item: Item[] = [ //dummy data
    new Item(
     'r1',
     'Martin',
     'assets/7.jpeg',
     'assets/two.jpeg',
     ),
];
...
 get item() {
    return [...this._item];
  }

  constructor() { }

  getItem(id: string) {
    return {...this._item.find(r => r.id === id)};
  }
```

itemdetail.ts

```
item: Item;  //store item data model
constructor() {}
...
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(paramMap => {
      if (!paramMap.has('id')) {
        this.router.navigate[('item')];
        return;
      }
      this.item = this.itemservice.getItem(paramMap.get('id'));
    }); 

}
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
    ...
     { path: 'itemdetail/:id', loadChildren: './itemdetail/itemdetail.module#ItemdetailPageModule' },
    ...
```

Comment: could you show me the structure of the `paramMap.get('id')` in your itemdetail.ts

Comment: which part do you mean exactly by that? The code above is all that concerns this issue or subject with passing the id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually solved the problem by using all of my code from the question BUT using a routerLink instead of a click event. `[routerLink]="['/itemdetail', item.id]`

Answer (score 0):

In your item.service, try:

```
//dummy data
 private _items: Item[] = [ 
    {
     id: 'r1',
     username: 'Martin',
     imageUrl: 'assets/7.jpeg',
     imageUrl2: 'assets/two.jpeg',
     },
];

 get item() {
    return [...this._items];
  }

  constructor() { }

  getItem(id: string) {
    let item: Item;
    for (let i = 0; i < this._items.length; i++) {
      if(this._items[i].id == id) {
         item = this._items[i];
         break;
      }
    }
   return item;
  }
```

In your item.ts, try:

```
openRankdet() {
    this.router.navigate(['itemdetail/' + this.item.id])
  }
```

Comment: if I try that I am not being navigated anymore:(

Comment: yes `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.item.id')`

Comment: in your ngOnInit, right after `this.item = this.itemservice.getItem(paramMap.get('id'));` add `console.log(this.item);` and see what you get.  You can change your router.navigate back to 'itemdetail/:id' but I'm guessing the url you'll see in the address bar after that is going to actually say /itemdetail/:id which is not what you want

Comment: since Im not being routed with your solution and `ngOnInit() {}` is not starting. I used my code from the question and consol logged it. Strangely I only logs: `{}`

Comment: So you have two problems, 1 being that you are not actually getting the item properly with `this.itemservice.getItem(paramMap.get('id'));`, since it's returning an empty object as is evidenced by you last comment.  And 2 that you are trying to route to /itemdetail/:id which is not an actual route, as you want it to be /itemdetail/1234 or whatever the item id is.  You need to figure out how to properly fetch your item object and then change your `openRankdet()` function to what I have in the answer above.

Comment: so the error is in the `openRankdet()` path and in this part `this.itemservice.getItem(paramMap.get('id'));` ?

Comment: Try changing your item service file to what I just added to my answer

Comment: I sadly can't use your path. Because I'm not navigated. Do you mean I have to change my path `'itemdetail/'`?

Comment: You'll need to use my path BUT only after you're sure you've actually gotten the correct item from calling `this.itemservice.getItem(paramMap.get('id'));`  Try my latest edit.

Comment: The reason the navigation won't work is because you're not actually getting an item from your service, just an empty object.  So, this.item.id is undefined.  Once you are sure you're getting an actual item in your ngOnInit, then that navigation path should work.

Comment: with your latest edit I still get an `undefined` in my console.